# wp_update_nav_menu_item creates new item in menu instead updating

Tags: wordpress

It doesn't update the item in nav menu.

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item(2,8522, array('menu-item-url' => home_url( '/page.php' )));
```

I think I used this function in right mode.

Comment: you haven't pass the second parameter $menu_item_db_id, so default it is o. So its adding a new item instead of replacing it.@Roma

Comment: Why are you updating the menu this way? The menu should be created from the backend in the Appearance > Menu menu.

Comment: I have passed it. The $menu_item_db_id is=8522

Comment: Right, the menu can be created from the backend,but I'm trying to set some  links from other site fore SEO.